# How to connect MySQL running on a web server from c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on an C# application which would use the remote MySQL database located in my website hosted on a Linux server with PHP & MySQL support.

I tried to connect directly to the MySQL database, but was not able to connect due to restrictions  at my hoster side.

can somebody help me please, can i do that with this restrictions ?

Comment: What's the error you get when you try to connect remotely? Have you spoken with your provider to confirm that they do not allow external database connections?

Comment: you will not be able to access the database if the connection port is not set to be open please ask your provider about the availability of the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to port 3306 on the remote machine. You can test if you have access to this port using telnet or similar

```
telnet ip 3306
```

These are the solutions you have:

A) **Create local dev environment**: You don't provide much information. If my guess is correct you are developing locally and later you plan to deploy your c# application to web server, that also will contain mysql db.

- Install mysql in your local machine
- Get a copy of the DB.
- Configure your C# program to connect to your local mysql (localhost:3306)
- When you deploy code it to your web server, it will connect also to your "localhost 3306" that will be the mysql installed into the web server.

B) **Use VPN to access mysql**: If A is not applicable another solution consist in installing some kind of VPN between web server containing mySQL and the pc running your application. Once VPN is setup and you can access port 3306 (by telnet as explained before), then your app will work.

C) **Open ports to access mysql**: The most easy solution is asking for administrator to open ports for you. 99% of the times the answer will be no, so I will not follow this route. (Maybe there is some kind of solution in your web provider that allows to open specific ports for a given IP, but I doubt it)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The server needs to have allowed remote connections and if this isn't possible, than you're out of your luck.

But, there may be another way... If you can create a web service on the server you're able to connect from, you should be able to communicate with the data in mysql virtually from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a way of API, if your server blocks incoming connections from web, just overload MySQL Functions you need to use with PHP and "echo" results as a server, parse them as a client with your c# application, it is the only way to organize such a system, or, you can allow incoming connection to MySQL, then watch on this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)